# Have Forgotten or Have forgot

Tags: past-participles

a) What is the past participle of forget, I mean Forgot or forgotten? 
b) Is it region Specific I mean British English or American English?

E.G.

a) I have forgot my keys at home.

b) I have forgotten my keys at home.

Answer (score 2):

Forgotten is the past participle. Forgot is the past form.
[vist this link for more information](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/forget)

"I have forgotten my keys at home" is the correct option.

Comment: In some dialects (I think we're talking sub-national dialects), it's sufficiently common to use *forgot* as a past participle (but *not* as an adjective) that it's hard to call it wrong in those dialects. International standard English, though, would have to be based on the numerically dominant pattern that *forgot* is the preterite (past simple) and *forgotten* is the past participle.

Answer (score 1):

At [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com) you can read:

> **Usage:**
>
> Both forgot and forgotten are used as the past participle of forget:
>
> > *Many have already forgot (or forgotten) the hard times of the Depression.*
>
> Only forgotten is used attributively:
>
> > *half-forgotten memories.*

Here's the [source to that quote](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/forgot).

If you just google for "I have forgot" (with the quotations marks included), you'll find plenty of results showing that the use of "forgot" as a substitute of "forgotten" is pretty common, though not really accepted as correct. And I'm pretty sure I've listened people in daily conversations to say a lot of times "I have forgot" (though I haven't really taken notes about how many times I've heard them doing so).